# error at npm install line, whyle creating an ionic project with ionic start

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic project by using

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type=ionic-angular
```

but there's an error at npm install line.
I've uninstall and reinstall node, but i still have the same problem. Look at the picture below to have a precise idea

[issue screen shoot in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKOP1.png)

I hope you guys can help. Thanks

Comment: Try to run `npm cache clean` first

Comment: It did not work

Comment: I uninstalled node.js, and deleted those folders C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm & C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache. 
After that I reinstalled node.js and ionic. Now everything is ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I uninstalled node.js from the control pannel, after that, I deleted those folders C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm & C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache. 
And finally I reinstalled node.js and ionic. Now everything is ok, i can create new projects again